# Unable to build project after adding Firebase Performance - Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, firebase-performance

I am trying to add Firebase Performance SDK to my project but am running into issues when building the project.

Everything will sync in Gradle without issue. Unfortunately, I am at a loss about what is happening here.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**Build output is throwing the following errors:**

```
  Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process: /…/…/app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/dev/75, /…/…/app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/dev/86, /…/…/app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/dev/87, ................. /…/…/grove_android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/dev/202, /…/…/app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/dev/203
```

```
:app:dexBuilderDev 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process: 
/.../.../app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/dev/75, 
/.../.../app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/dev/76, 
/.../.../app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/dev/77, 
………
/.../.../app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/dev/201,
/.../.../app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/dev/202,
/.../.../app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/dev/203 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected non-class file: 
METAINF/versions/9/org/junit/platform/commons/util/ModuleUtils.class Unexpected non-class file: META-INF/versions/9/org/junit/platform/commons/util/ModuleUtils.class
```

**Build.Grade (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
     .
     .
     .
}

dependencies {
    .
    .
    .
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.8'
    .
    .
    .
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
```

**Build.Gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Didn't find a solution but here is a well-known workaround

```
if (!project.hasProperty("disable-performance-plugin")) {
    project.plugins.apply(Plugins.Project.FIREBASE_PERF)
}
```

and then run your build with

```
-Pdisable-performance-plugin
```